# Is "The mall is constructing" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct: "The mall is constructing".?

I know that we use "The mall is being constructed" in passive, but I want to know that can I write "The mall is constructing". Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: The mall is constructing is ungrammatical, because the verb *construct* is transitive. The mall is constructing *what*? (leaving alone the face that the mall is not something that can construct anything).

Comment: It used to be grammatical to say that; 200 or less years ago many English speakers would say things like _The bridge is building_. Of course, they wouldn't know what to say about a mall back then, and _constructing_ would sound pretty highfalutin. Nowadays, however, we either use a fixed phrase _under construction_ or a passive _is being constructed_.

Comment: This should not have been closed as proofreading, because the asker did identify a specific source of concern in the text (i.e., use of the verb *constructing* in active voice).

Comment: I knew I'd come across the intransitive usage before. In ['The Elements of Mechanics'](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vvs4AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=%22bridge+is+constructing%22&source=bl&ots=kUMZwlum40&sig=CEGnDtIxK98C3_KlqereSxhK-0U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8FI4VKXtLsXY7AaIzoHgDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bridge%20is%20constructing%22&f=false) [1832] by James Renwick is 'At the present moment a bridge is constructing over the Dee at Chester, in England, whose span is 200 feet.' [No, I didn't buy a copy of the original when it was printed.]

Answer (score 1):

Its grammatically correct in a technical sense, I suppose. However it is almost certainly not what you are trying to say.

The verb "constructing" means that the subject is doing the constructing. Malls themselves are buildings, and to my knowledge can't really be said to actively do much of anything on their own, other than perhaps sell stuff or quash the human spirit.

If you mean that some people (perhaps employed by the owners of the mall) are in the process of building it, the typical phrase to use would be "The mall is under construction".

Answer (score 0):

The mall is "**under-construction**".

[The meaning of the verb](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/construct?s=t)...**construct** is to build up, create, design, put together, or manufacture.

From what you have stated, it appears as if the subject, **"the mall", is constructing itself.**